# Different site languages for different users

Tags: dashboard, multi-language

Is there a way to have the WordPress site language - specifically the language used in the admin areas - be different for different users? I would like to have administrators be able to select either a Persian or an English display for the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change language with login you may use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/

PS. Some plugins or themes may not support localization.

Comment: That plugin seems to be outdated. What I want to know is how to do what it is doing for getting multi-language support in the admin area,

Comment: Core admin dashboard is multi-language yet. However there is no interface to change language at each login or to each user. The interface must be supplied by plugin. If you can to develop it, you may change global variable `$locale` to user custom value or(and) append a language field to login page.

Comment: Sorry. Set variable `$locale` is a wrong way. Better way is to add filter `locale` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/locale).